# Products excluding each element of the array

Tags: java, algorithm, array

Given an array of integers, return a new array such that each element at index i of the new array is the product of all the numbers in the original array except the one at i.

For example, if our input was [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], the expected output would be [120, 60, 40, 30, 24]. If our input was [3, 2, 1], the expected output would be [2, 3, 6].

Is there a better solution for this problem?

> Note: Division is not allowed.

```
public class DailyCodingProblem2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        int[] ans = solution(arr, arr.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));

        arr = new int[] { 3, 2, 1 };
        ans = solution(arr, arr.length);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));
    }

    private static int[] solution(int[] arr, int n) {
        int[] left = new int[n];
        int[] right = new int[n];
        int[] res = new int[n];
        left[0] = 1;
        right[n - 1] = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            left[i] = arr[i - 1] * left[i - 1];
        }

        for (int i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            right[i] = arr[i + 1] * right[i + 1];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            res[i] = left[i] * right[i];
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: "Note: Division is not allowed." Why? Is it because of a restriction for the assignment?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Yes it is a restriction for the assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time complexity-wise, I think not. You're required to 'visit' all numbers, and your solution is `O(n)`, so that can't be improved.

Code clarity could be improved, as it's not very obvious what the intention is. Some **comments** would help that.
I think shifting indices by 1 might make it clearer (`left[i+1] = arr[i] * left[i]`), but then maybe not because it'd mess up the last loop.

Have you explored different algorithms? I wonder if straightforward memoization makes a very clear solution for this.